# Oracle DB Providers installation scripts errors

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

After installing Oracle XE DB and ODP.NET, i tried to run included scripts to establish tables for .NET providers. When i try to run for example InstallOracleMembership.sql, the operation fails with folowing errors:

```
IF ( ora_aspnet_TableExists('ORA_ASPNET_MEMBERSHIP') = 0)   THEN
      *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 11:
PLS-00201: identifier 'ORA_ASPNET_TABLEEXISTS' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 6:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Then comes some warnings -> Warning: Function created with compilation errors.
And the more errors:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ora_vw_aspnet_Applications TO ora_aspnet_Mem_ReportAccess
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

                .
                .
                .
GRANT ora_aspnet_Mem_BasicAccess TO ora_aspnet_Mem_FullAccess
                                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01917: user or role 'ORA_ASPNET_MEM_FULLACCESS' does not exist
```

For this purpose i created user and added him privileges like create role, view, table according to this tutorial [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28844/installation.htm#BABDEHAJ)
I am using ODAC 11.2 Release 4 (11.2.0.3.0) 32bit, Oracle 11g R2 XE DB, Win7 Professional 64bit and VS2010.

Am i something missing? What i am doing wrong? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual says you need to run **$ORACLE_HOME\ASP.NET\sql\InstallOracleASPNETCommon.sql** install script before any other install scripts.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10767/installation.htm

Comment: yes i found out, but InstallOracleASPNETCommon.sql needs to run also before InstallAllOracleASPNETProviders.sql and that tutorial doesnt mention it so i was confused when posting this question, but thanks anyway